# Why this is not right by using synchronized (Java concurrency) in this example?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two Java classes as below...

(1) JavaClass SyncTest: It defines a class (implementing Runnable) and invokes a "synchronized" method (named "call") defined in Class SyncTestCalled

(2) JavaClass SyncTestCalled : There is one synchronized method.

```
------
    After calling from main(), I am thinking it should output something like:  
[Two]
[Three]
[One]

But, it outputs something like this (note the open bracket which is not paired in right locations) : 

[[[Two]
Three]
One]
```

What's wrong with the codes? Please help. Thanks a lot!

---

```
    Here is the code of these two classes...


    public class SyncTest implements Runnable {    
        Thread t;   
        String name;
        SyncTestCalled syncTestCalled;    
        public SyncTest(String name) {
                t = new Thread(this, name);
                syncTestCalled = new SyncTestCalled();
                this.name = name;
                t.start();
        }    
        public void run() {             
                syncTestCalled.call(this.name);
        }       
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SyncTest syncTest1 = new SyncTest("One");
                SyncTest syncTest2 = new SyncTest("Two");
                SyncTest syncTest3 = new SyncTest("Three");
        }   
      } // of class SyncTest
    public class SyncTestCalled {
        public SyncTestCalled() {
        // Do nothing
        }    
        synchronized public void call(String message) {
                System.out.print("[");
                try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                     System.out.print(message);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("]");
        }
    } // of class SyncTestCalled
```

Comment: what error u are getting ???

Comment: @Ronak Bhatt, I am trying to make the SyncTestCalled.call the atomic access...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `synchronized` as part of the method declaration, Java attempts to acquire the monitor (lock) on the object the method is invoked on. So a method like

```
synchronized public void call(String message) {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void call(String message) {
    synchronized (this) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In your code, you create three different `SyncTestCalled` objects and pass each individual one to the different `SyncTest` instances. In other words, nothing is coordinated. Each call to

```
syncTestCalled.call(this.name);
```

is synchronized on a different object and therefore none of the threads need to wait on the others.

It's up to the Thread scheduler who gets where first, so you get output like

```
[[[Two]
Three]
One]
```

or

```
[[[OneThree]
Two]
]
```

---

Note that `Thread.sleep(long)` does not relinquish any monitors the thread currently has.

Comment: @Bohemian `PrintStream` synchronizes on `this` as well on every write, so every `out.println()` will be "ACID", but their ordering is not guaranteed.

Comment: @SunnyChen Exactly, make one `syncTestCalled` and have all your `SyncTest` objects use it.

Comment: @SunnyChen Code doesn't appear well in comments. IF there is something you want to add, add it to your question.

Comment: I am new to Java (and stackoverflow)... I meant to say if I change the constructor SyncTest(String name) to SyncTest(String name, SyncTestCalled syncTestCalled) and pass
make "only one" syncTestCalled in main() like SyncTest syncTest1 = new SyncTest("One", syncTestCalled);
... It looks I got your answer already :} Thanks.

Comment: @sunny You're welcome. Consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer(s) that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread can invoke your `call()` method on a given instance at any given time. But what you want is atomicity for several calls to `System.out.print()` methods. For that, you need to acquire a lock on `System.out` instead:

```
synchronized (System.out) {
  System.out.print('[');
  System.out.print(message);
  System.out.println(']');
}
```

Because `PrintStream` locks on itself, this will prevent other threads from interleaving their own calls to `print()`.